# Find all holomorphic functions satisfying the following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Theres 2 parts a) and b) which are disjoint, I think I got a) right have no idea how to do b):

a) Find all holomporphic functions in $\mathbb D$ (the unit disk) that satisfy $f(\frac{1}{2})=3$ and $|f(z)| \leq 3$ if $|z| \leq 1$.

Since $f(\frac{1}{2}) \geq  f(z)$ for $z \in \mathbb D$ the maximum modulus principle states that $f$ is constant. Seems a bit too easy but I think that's it.

b) Find al holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb C \rightarrow C$ satisfying $f(x)=sin(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

This is the one I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a) is fine. For part (b), you need the following fact, called the identity theorem.

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two holomorphic functions defined on a connected open subset of $\mathbb C$. If the set of points $z$ such that $f(z)=g(z)$ possesses an accumulation point, then $f$ and $g$ are the same function.

(An accumulation point $p$ of a set $S$ is a point such that every open ball around $p$ with $p$ removed contains some other element of $S$. The real axis $\mathbb R$ has lots of accumulation points.)

The identity theorem gives rise to the so-called [principle of permanence of functional equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofPermanence.html), which implies in particular that if a complex-analytic function satisfies a functional equation on the real axis, then it satisfies it everywhere.

Do you see now what the function in part (b) has to be?